# Find a point symmetrical to another point in relation to a line

Tags: vectors

Find the point Q that is symmetric to point $P(-1,-2,1)$ in relation to line $l: \frac{x}{-2}=\frac{y-3}{4}=\frac{z-4}{1}$ as well as projection P' of point P onto line l.

1) I guess we start off with a parallel vector with a line (ie, $\langle -2,4,1 \rangle$) and then rotate it such way that it points to point P. If we call the line's vector $\langle-2,4,1 \rangle =C$, then we need to find some point that lies on the line X such that vector XP is orthogonal to vector c. That way we'd have a vector pointing from the line to the P.

2) Then we take that vector, basically scale it by $-1$ and say - "there should be point Q"?

3) Point P' would in this case be exactly point X?

Is this thought-process valid what-so-ever?

Thanks! :)

Comment: don't follow what you mean rotate $\langle -2,4,1 \rangle$ ... the moment you rotate it, it is no longer $\langle -2,4,1 \rangle$. It sounds right anyway but needs more details, how do you do all that? Maybe rewrite the line parametrically $x=-2t, y=4t+3, z=t+4$ and then find the value of $t$ for which the vector $\langle x,y,z \rangle-P=\langle -2t+1,4t+5,t+3 \rangle$ is orthogonal to $\langle -2,4,1 \rangle$ (that is dot product is zero). This value of $t$ will give you the point on the line you are looking for. Will write complete answer but only if you ask (you seemed to only need a hint).

Comment: hmm just noticed the OP had not logged in for almost an year ... I doubt he is interested in the answer at this point, but the question got edited and showed on top